# Status pooling in angular frontend

Tags: angularjs, frontend

I am working on a project where we have server that is administrated from angular web page, and I noticed that it is calling this main server REST interface for status update each second.

My questions: Is it a proper technique to solve this kind of problems?
If not how do I properly make such regular updates in more reactive or event way from back to front end?

I was thinking about reworking to maybe keeping the session opened for longer period and update only on change of status, and retry on session expiration.

Comment: Web sockets is the answer.

Comment: Wanted simpler mechanism than this.

Comment: Either pull or push.

Comment: if you want simpler, take a look at long polling